# access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)

Tags: delphi, mysql

Бросаю на форму компонент `SQLconnection` соответственно настраиваю, пытаюсь подключаться к MySQL и выдается такое сообщение

> "access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)"

`libmysql.dll` скопировал в bin (папка делфи) и в `system32`,
в `phpmyadmin` пароль не ставился пользователь `rootconfig.default.php` и `config.inc.php` так же паролей нет

Comment: Вообще, при работе c MySQL нужно запустить сервак, Вы запустили?

Comment: нет конечно, phpmyadmin сам по себе работает, конечно работает

Comment: То есть сам по себе?

Comment: тоесть mysql включен и работает, а вот средствами делфи подключитьтся не получается, хотя все делал как требуется

Comment: Как вариант, скачайте с mysql.com пакет установки, установите, в конце установки поставьте галочку, чтобы установить как службу в Windows ( если у вас винда ) После через cmd запускаем C:\net start mysql5.5 (службе даём название mysql5.5) запускаем делфи, кидаем контролы, пробуем!

Comment: Пользователь root?

Comment: Может быть стоит явно указать, что пароль пустой?

Comment: LLIAKAJI Я понимаю, что его нет. Просто в некоторых языках, если не объявить переменную, то при её вызове возвращается не то, что ожидается.

Comment: и что же тогда конкретно нужно сделать что бы избежать этой ошибки?

Comment: @LLIAKAJI не знаю, я просто привел пример :-)

Comment: mysql это язык программирования?

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, mysql - это СУБД

Comment: >  пароль не ставился 

> access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password yes)

Ошибка как бы говорит, что вы пытаетесь подключиться под пользователем 'root'@'localhost', используя пароль. Но кто читает сообщения об ошибках...

Answer (score 1):

Настройте права в MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Какие настройки в делфи сделал?

В компоненте **SimpleDataSet**? **LoginPrompt** везде какой стоит **true или false**?

Можно сделать нового пользователя.

1. Компонент **SimpleDataSet** правой кнопкой жмякнуть выбрать **Edit connection -> Mysql connection** там вставить правильные данные для подключения к БД.

ps там же все просто подключается. файл в корень программы можно кинуть, настроить связку 2х компонентов, прописать данные для входа в БД и все, вуаля готово.

Answer (score 1):

Неверный логин, пароль или хост

1. Проверьте кодировку ввода
2. Пустой пароль тоже пароль
3. Проверьте регистр букв

Comment: Не совсем. По крайней мере в данном контексте. MySQL как-бы считает, что, если пароль пустой, то его нет. Соответственно `using password: NO`

Comment: я не знаю как написан этот компонент. возможно там есть два свойства password_enable := true/false и password := "". я два года в делфях не сидел. написал чтоб застраховаться от подобного случая, проверить ведь не мешает